# Imgur uploads working via client-side javascript but not node.js. Flummoxed

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, imgur

This works:

```
    $.post( 
        'http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json', 
        { 
            key: 'dsfdwerwersf53534dfsfse3', 
            image: 'http://i.imgur.com/UH17u.png' 
        }, 
        function( data ) { console.log( data.upload.links.original ); }
    );
```

When I run this in Chrome's console, imgur sends me the url of the uploaded image right away: `http://i.imgur.com/KrHMY.png`. Excellent.

.

Now I'm try the same thing on the server-side using node.js but it doesn't work:

```
    var 
        express = require( 'express' )
    ,   app = express.createServer()
    ,   request = require( 'superagent' );


    app.get( '/', function( req, res ) {
        request
            .post( 'http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json' )
            .send( { key: 'dsfdwerwersf53534dfsfse3', image: 'http://i.imgur.com/UH17u.png' } )
            .end( function( data ) {
                console.log( data.upload.links.original );
            });
    });

    app.listen( '8080' );
```

When I run the node.js app, imgur sends back this response:

```
text: '{"error":{"message":"No API key was sent, and no user is authenticated","request":"\\/2\\/upload.json","method":"post","format":"json","parameters":"image = {\\"key\\":\\"dsfdwerwersf53534dfsfse3\\",\\"image\\":\\"http:\\/\\/i.imgur.com\\/UH17u.png\\"}"}}',
```

The key part is this: `No API key was sent`. Why isn't imgur recognizing the `key` I'm sending with the `POST`?

I've tried using both `request` and `superagent` modules. I feel silly not being able to figure out why something so simple isn't working. Appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery does sometime so much magie that it is hard to see it.

Here I'd bet two thing either, I have not used superagent in month and I had stupid error like this one that made me sad.

But here I bet that the body is a to string at best a json or your object.
JQuery by default urlencode just like most API want the POST body to be.
Use

```
var = require('querystring');
/*...*/
.send(qs.encode({ key: '...', image: '...' }))
```

Comment: You did in 30 seconds what I couldn't do in 4 hours. Worked like a charm, thanks mate.